# SBT AutoPlugins conflict that shouldn't be there

Tags: scala, sbt, flyway, twirl

I have a sbt project using FlyWay. It's disabled in most projects because we're only running the evolutions from a specific project.

So I have something like this:

```
lazy val master = project
  .disablePlugins(FlywayPlugin)
  .aggregate(common)
  .dependsOn(common)
```

The project works fine. It compiles, works, tests pass, etc.

Now I want to add Twirl, so I do this (in addition to `plugins.sbt` of course):

```
lazy val master = project
  .enablePlugins(SbtTwirl)
  .disablePlugins(FlywayPlugin)
  .aggregate(common)
  .dependsOn(common)
```

And I end up with this error:

```
[error] sbt.AutoPluginException: Error determining plugins for project 'master' in /opt/app/master:
[error] Contradiction in selected plugins.  These plugins were both included and excluded: org.flywaydb.sbt.FlywayPlugin
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Which I don't really understand because I didn't change anything about `FlyWay`.

What could cause that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem. `FlywayPlugin` gets automatically enabled on all (sub)projects and when you try to disable it, it causes the conflict.

See [sbt/sbt#1926](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1926). Citing @jsuereth:

> Yeah, this is a known issue in our logic system (and the translation of enablement/disablement into it). I'm working on a mechanism to fix it.
>
> PRs welcome if you have time.

There is also an open issue in the Flyway repository: [flyway/flyway#1329](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1329) which suggests not to enable it automatically. But so far there is no solution or a workaround there.